# JqGrid NavGrid refresh not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcjqgrid

after create or edit the grid is not getting dynamically updated.Please suggest any solution, below my script.I have enabled **refresh : true** , but still the grid is not getting refreshed.

//load grid

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/MVC/GetGrid",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Task Name', 'Task Description', 'Target Date', 'Severity', 'Task Status'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id' },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskName', index: 'TaskName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskDescription', index: 'TaskDescription', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TargetDate', index: 'TargetDate', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/M/y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y', editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); } } },
            { key: false, name: 'Severity', index: 'Severity', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'L': 'Low', 'M': 'Medium', 'H': 'High' } } },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskStatus', index: 'TaskStatus', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'A': 'Active', 'I': 'InActive' } } },
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        caption: 'Error Grid',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display!',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false
    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },

    //Edit
    {
        zindex: 100,
        url: '/MVC/Edit',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);                
            }
        }        
    },
    //Add
    {
        zindex: 100,
        url: '/MVC/Create',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alret(response.responseText);                
            }
        }
    },
    //Delete
    {
        zindex: 100,
        url: '/MVC/Delete',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this hierarchy..?",
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alret(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    }).navButtonAdd('#pager', {
        caption: "Excel", onClickButton: function () {
            DataGrid.jqGrid('excelExport', { url: '/MVC/ExportToExcel' });
        },
        position: "last",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink"
    });
});
```